# How to modify this LINQ statement to show bundles with count < 3 instead of CountWithinBundle < 3

Tags: c#, linq

I am creating bundles in my app and a bundle is defined as follows

Having a BundleId != null
Having a CountWithinBundle
A bundle is "full" when it has 3 members

I am trying to write a query to find "non full" bundles, below is where I am at but it gives me the second within a bundle every time since I am using the < 3

How can I modify this so that it gives me the last"non full" bundle Item, i,e an ItemInBasket where there are less than 3 entries with the same bundleId and Department so I can add a new item into the same bundle

```
var itemInBasket = basketToUpdate.ItemsInBasket.OrderByDescending(c => c.ThisItemsCountWithinBundle)
                                                                   .Where(s => !string.IsNullOrEmpty(s.BundleId))
                                                                   .Where(i => i.ThisItemsCountWithinBundle < 3)
                                                                   .Where(s => s.Item.Department == itemToAdd.Item.Department)
                                                                   .FirstOrDefault();
```

the class model looks like this

```
using Newtonsoft.Json;
using System;
using System.Collections.Generic;
using System.Text;

namespace slapi.Models
{
    class BasketModel
    {
        [JsonProperty(PropertyName = "id")]
        public string Id { get; set; }
        public string UserId { get; set; }
        public string Brand { get; set; }
        public int BasketLevel { get; set; }
        //Start New Basket props
        public int MaxBasketLevel { get; set; } = 6;
        public Nullable<decimal> BasketLevelProgress { get; set; }
        public decimal BasketLevelDiscount { get; set; }
        public decimal WhitePriceStoreSummary { get; set; }
        public Nullable<decimal> RedPriceStoreSummary { get; set; }
        public Nullable<decimal> CheckoutDiscount { get; set; }
        public Nullable<decimal> CheckoutDiscountPercent { get; set; }
        public string Currency { get; set; } = "SEK";
        public List<XForYStatusInformation> XForYInformations { get; set; }
        //End New Basket props
        public string ConsumerName { get; set; }
        public string StoreId { get; set; }
        public bool IsRedeemed { get; set; } = false;
        public bool IsDeleted { get; set; } = false;
        public List<ItemInBasket> ItemsInBasket { get; set; }
        public string CreatedDate { get; set; }
        public string CreatedDateUtc { get; set; }
        public string CreatedBy { get; set; }
        public string UpdatedDate { get; set; }
        public string UpdatedDateUtc { get; set; }
        public string UpdatedBy { get; set; }
        public Nullable<int> CountHistory { get; set; } = 0;
    }

    class ItemInBasket
    {
        public StorelensItemModel_V2 Item { get; set; }
        public Nullable<int> ItemRowPosition { get; set; }
        public bool UsedForWeightCalculation { get; set; }
        public bool IsPaused { get; set; }
        public string BundleId { get; set; }
        public int ThisItemsCountWithinBundle { get; set; } = 0;
        public int BundleNeededQty { get; set; } = 3;

    }

    class XForYStatusInformation 
    {
        public string Sticker { get; set; }
        public string Text { get; set; }
        public string BundleId { get; set; }
        public string Department { get; set; }
    }
}
```

Comment: Instead of writing separate where clause, use && in single where statment

Comment: what is the definition of last here ?

Comment: @EhsanSajjad by Last I mean the first Item since I am OrderByDescending on the ThisItemsCountWithinBundle, so it could be 1,2 or 3 and I want the highest one in non full bundles so it really can only be 1 or 2 since if it was 3 the bundle would be full

Comment: @GertArnold the model is very simple it only has BundleId, ThisItemsCountWithinBundle , Item and QtyNeededForBundle, for every item we insert in basket, we set a BundleId and if its a second item with the same Department then we add it to the same bundle by setting the same BundleId and increasing the ThisItemsCountWithinBundle with 1 for that item until we reach 3 then it is full, my code works for the first bundle, but once I fill one bundle every new item will be added as item 3 to that same bundle

Comment: @GertArnold I guess another way to state what I need is, var itemInBasket = the first ItemInBasket where its bundleId has a count() less than 3

Answer (score 0, accepted):

The problem is that you're querying individual items, so you lose their mutual relationships (i.e. belonging to the same basket). The `basketToUpdate` has all required information, basically something like this:

```cs
basketToUpdate
    .Select(b => new
    {
        Bundles = b.ItemsInBasket
                   .GroupBy(i => i.BundleId)
                   .Select(g => new
                   {
                        BundleId = g.Key,
                        ItemCount = g.Count(),
                        LastItem = g.OrderByDescending(c => c.ThisItemsCountWithinBundle)
                                    .FirstOrDefault()
                   })
    })
    .Where(x => x.Bundles.Any(b => ItemCount < 3))
```

This gives you baskets with non-full bundles in which you can filter the bundles with `ItemCount < 3`.

I don't know the function of this `s.Item.Department == itemToAdd.Item.Department` predicate, so I didn't try to fit it in.

Comment: This has the same problem as my code I think, because the ItemsInBasket.Count() will count through all bundles, what if there are 4 bundles with 4 different bundleIds? and only the 3d one is not "full"? i,e does not have 3 items with the same bundleId because ThisItemsCountWithinBundle starts over for each bundleID so ID 1 can have countWithinBundle same as bundleID 2

Comment: I added the class model in the question, sorry for missing that