# How to remove items with count == 3 using LINQ

Tags: c#, linq

I have the following

```
var itemRowsAvailableToMoveToBrokenBundle = customerBasket.ItemsInBasket.Where(s => !string.IsNullOrEmpty(s.BundleId)
                                                                                     && s.Item.Department == removedIem.Item.Department);
```

Now I am trying to remove all items from `itemRowsAvailableToMoveToBrokenBundle`where the bundleId makes it so that they have a count == 3, for example if three ItemInBasket have bundleId == "1" then I want to remove them.

I tried using .count() but I cant figure out how to do it across several bundles because if I specify a bundleId and count() it only gives me that specific bundle, I want to remove ALL bundles with a count == 3

Comment: Exactly 3 or >= 3?

Comment: @Steve Exactly 3, a bundle is defined as "full" when it has exactly 3 items with the same bundleId, if a fourth item is added to basket it gets a new bundleId so I Am trying to remove all "Full" bundles so I can find the ones ( if any ) where I can insert new items

Comment: That's only a small modification of the query I showed you [before](https://stackoverflow.com/a/63280546/861716).

Answer (score 4, accepted):

You can apply the [groupBy](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/dotnet/csharp/linq/group-query-results) on `BundleId` to see the count and apply the condition accordingly.

```
itemRowsAvailableToMoveToBrokenBundle  = itemRowsAvailableToMoveToBrokenBundle 
                                           .GroupBy(i => i.BundleId)
                                           .Where(i => i.Count() != 3)
                                           .SelectMany(i => i);
```

Above code will remove all budndleId which have count equal to 3.

Comment: @mjwills - As such it is not needed. I've updated my answer. Thanks for pointing out.